I can't figure out how to make this highlighted field orange before making a move
It doesn't reproduce in the console so I can't catch.

The current CSS:
@-moz-document domain("lichess.org") {
    .is2d cg-board::before {
        background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/0fgKmzv/mychessboard.png') !important;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .check {
        background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ab5700c9 15%, #ffab54c9 40%, rgba(169, 0, 0, 0) 89%, rgba(158, 0, 0, 0) 100%)!important;
    }
    .selected {
        background-color: #ffab54c9 !important;
    }
    .move-dest {
        color: #ffab54c9 !important;
        background: radial-gradient(#ffab54c9 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%);
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
    square.move-dest {
        background: radial-gradient(#ffab54c9 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%);
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
    .move-dest oc {
        background-color: #ffab54c9 !important;
    }
    square.oc.move-dest {
        background: radial-gradient(#ffab54c9 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%);
        background: radial-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent 79%, #ffab54c9 80%);
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
    .last-move {
        background-color: #ffab54c9 !important;
    }
    square.last-move {
        will-change: transform;
        background-color: #ffab54c9;
    }
    square.last-move {
        will-change: transform;
        background: radial-gradient(transparent 0%, #ffab54c9 79%, #ffab54c9 80%);
    }
    .current-premove {
        background-color: #ffab54c9 !important;
    }
    .last-move-current-premove {
        background-color: #ffab54c9 !important;
    }
    .last-move-selected {
        background-color: #ffab54c9 !important;
    }
}
line[stroke="#15781B"] {
    stroke: #c96601c9 !important
}
path[fill="#15781B"] {
    fill: #c96601c9 !important
}
circle[stroke="#15781B"] {
    stroke: #c96601c9 !important
}


Is this a question about lichess interface settings, or are you trying to modify the CSS? I'd encourage you to be a lot clearer about exactly what you're trying to achieve
